# Puppet: Error 400 on SERVER: Permission denied

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-foreman

I would like to use DOCSF-module (from github). If I try to use it I'm getting this result:

```
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Error 400 on SERVER: Permission denied - /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/docsf/metadata.json
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppetmaster.example.com/pluginfacts: Error 400 on SERVER: Permission denied - /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/docsf/metadata.json
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Error 400 on SERVER: Permission denied - /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/docsf/metadata.json
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppetmaster.example.com/plugins: Error 400 on SERVER: Permission denied - /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/docsf/metadata.json
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Permission denied - /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/docsf/metadata.json on node pp-testexample.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

These are the file-permissions on the module:

```
-r--r--r--. 1 puppet root  734 24. Jun 2014  checksums.json
drwxrwxr-x. 3 puppet root   19 15. Sep 2015  lib
-r--r--r--. 1 puppet root  651 15. Sep 2015  LICENSE
drwxr-sr-x. 2 puppet root   71 15. Sep 2015  manifests
-r--r--r--. 1 puppet root  792 15. Sep 2015  metadata.json
-r--r--r--. 1 puppet root 2770 15. Sep 2015  README.md
drwxr-xr-x. 2 puppet root   27 15. Sep 2015  spec
drwxr-xr-x. 2 puppet root 4096 15. Sep 2015  templates
drwxr-xr-x. 2 puppet root   20 15. Sep 2015  tests
```

And this is the tree:

```
├── checksums.json
├── lib
│   └── facter
│       └── configserver_firewall.rb
├── LICENSE
├── manifests
│   ├── init.pp
│   ├── params.pp
│   ├── postinit.pp
│   └── preinit.pp
├── metadata.json
├── README.md
├── spec
│   └── spec_helper.rb
├── templates
│   ├── conf.maldet.erb
│   ├── csf.allow.erb
│   ├── csf.conf.erb
│   ├── csf.fignore.erb
│   ├── csf.ignore.erb
│   └── csf.pignore.erb
└── tests
    └── init.pp
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add the output of: ls -ld /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/docsf?

Answer (score 2):

Another problem could be SELinux policies. Try running restorcon on the files.

> restorcon -r /etc/puppet/files/

Answer (score 1):

Files inside puppet modules need to be `0644` at a minimum. There are a few examples of this around github:

https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/FORGE-163

https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-collectd/issues/179

https://github.com/rodjek/librarian-puppet/issues/251

Just change the perms to match the other files and you should be okay

Comment: Hi and thank you very much. I ran `chmod -c 0644` inside the manifests-folder but it did not solve the problem. All other files are already 0644 at least.